# ErrorError when running phpunit: Exception: file_put_contents(/meta/services.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm a novice developer trying to get phpunit set up in an already developed app but I get the following error on all my tests when I try to run phpunit:

ErrorException: file_put_contents(/meta/services.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

I did not develop the app or set any of its configurations and I'm woefully inexperienced so I don't know where to go with this.  I DO have a services.json file in app/storage/meta but phpunit seems to be looking for it in the root directory and I have no idea why or how to point it to the right place.

Comment: you should find at which line this `file_put_contents` call happens, and then you'll find how to fix it here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: If you're application works fine but just running tests get this error, the problem must be in your bootstrap file. Can you please show us your autoload.php and phpunit.xml?

Comment: <?php

// autoload.php @generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer' . '/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit...::getLoader();

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         syntaxCheck="false"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory>./app/tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>

Comment: When tracing through the error(in particular, the compiled.php file), it looks like the error is coming from the writing the "manifest".  However, I'm pretty lost as to what this implies or how to fix it.